# Why do I keep getting Nan as output?

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to write a simple gradient descent algorithm in C++ (for 10,000 iterations). Here is my program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  double learnrate=10; 
  double x=10.0; //initial start value

  for(int h=1; h<=10000; h++){
     x=x-learnrate*(2*x + 100*cos(100*x));
  }

  cout<<"The minimum is at y = "<<x*x + sin(100*x)<<" and at x = "<<x;

  return 0;
}
```

The output ends up being: y=nan and x=nan. I tried looking at the values of x and y by putting them into a file, and after a certain amount of iterations, I am getting all nans (for x and y). edit: I picked the learning rate (or step size) to be 10 as an experiment, I will use much smaller values afterwards.

Comment: What is the value of `x` right before it becomes `NaN`?

Comment: ensure all of your operations involve doubles and that your integer literals/consts aren't causing implicit conversions.

Comment: Hi. The last x value before nan, is: -1.7761e+307. If it matters, the last value for y is 3.96343e+307 and then afterwards, for several more values, it says "inf" for y, and x still has numbered values and then x and y both become nan. (@NathanOliver)

Comment: Assuming the formula is correct gradient descent, the values you are using are wrong as the values go to infinity as pointed out by other users

Comment: (@Dai) Hi. I changed all of the numbers and variables to decimal form (10.0, 2.0, 100.0), but I am still getting the same output (nan)

Comment: (@Tyler) The values of x you mean?

Answer (score 1):

There must be something wrong with your formula. Already the first 10 values of x are increasing like hell:

```
-752.379
15290.7
-290852
5.52555e+06
-1.04984e+08
1.9947e+09
-3.78994e+10
7.20088e+11
-1.36817e+13
2.59952e+14
```

No matter what starting value you choose the absolute value of the next `x` will be bigger.

```
|next_x| = | x - 20 * x - 100 * cos(100*x) |
```

For example consider what happens when you choose a very small starting value (`|x|->0`), then

```
|next_x| = | 0 - 20 * 0 - 100 * cos ( 0 ) | = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Print `x` before the call to the cosine function and you will see that the last number printed before `NaN` (at `h = 240`) is:

> -1.7761e+307

This means that the value is going to infinity, which cannot be represented (thus Not a Number).

It overflows the `double` type.

If you use `long double`, you will succeed in 1000 iterations, but you will still overflow the type with 10000 iterations.

So the problem is that the parameter `learnrate` is just too big. You should do let steps, while using a data type with larger range, as I suggested above.

Comment: Oh thank you! Sorry, I did not see your comment until now. I suspected tha was the issue, should I convert my initial value of x to radians?

Comment: @user8697693 I don't really remember now. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, but one more queastion: what about my formula is wrong?

Comment: The formula is not "wrong"; It's just bad. The parameter "learnrate" is too big. Gradient descent has lot's of problems, and it's slowwwwwww.

Comment: I'd rather improve it @JiveDadson. If you want, please help me improve it. =)

Comment: (@ Jive Dadson) thank you! Yes, someone told me the learnrate was too big and so it overshoots.

Comment: @user8697693 you just have to decrease your `learnrate`, nothing else. Or of course pick a new algorithm. By the way you have many answers here, *accept* the one that helped you more.

Answer (score 0):

Because at h=240 the variable "x" exceeds the limits of double type (1.79769e+308). This is a diverging arithmetic progression. You need to reduce your learn rate.

A couple of more things:
1- Do not use "using namespace std;" it is bad practice.
2- You can use "std::isnan() function to identify this situation.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iomanip>

#include <limits>
int main()
{


  double learnrate = 10.0;

  double x = 10.0; //initial start value

  std::cout<<"double type maximum=" << std::numeric_limits<double>::max()<<std::endl;
  bool failed = false;
  for (int h = 1; h <= 10000; h++)
  {

    x = x - learnrate*(2.0*x + 100.0 * std::cos(100.0 * x));
    if (std::isnan(x))
    {
      failed = true;
      std::cout << " Nan detected at h=" << h << std::endl;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!failed)
  std::cout << "The minimum is at y = " << x*x + std::sin(100.0*x) << " and at x = " << x;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While I don't typically use "using namespace std" in my cpp files, I would not call it bad practise. Using in in one's header files is bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

The "learn rate" is far too high. Change it to 1e-4, for example, and the program works, for an initial value of 10 at least. When the learnrate is 10, the iterations jump too far past the solution.

At its best, gradient descent is not a good algorithm. For serious applications you want to use something better. Much better. Search for Brent optimizer and BFGS.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out right now. Okay just did my output was: The minimum is at y=-0.97581 and at x=-0.15399.This algorithm (if I did it right) was just for my own practice :). I just checked the graph of the function: y=x^2 + sine(100x) (the integral of my derivative) and one of the local minimums is around those numbers.  I will also check out that Brent Optimizer too later!